# How do I get Bazel to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, tensorflow, bazel

I've seen this question a few times, but never any satisfactory answer. I am trying to build tensorflow on linux for non-x86 platforms (or just upgrade bazel itself to do so) I have no root access.

I've tried various settings for `--noincompatible_strict_action_env` and `--action_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH --test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and still end up with errors like this:

```
ERROR: /mnt/sfox/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sfox/367cbf405c0894135be861c1e3dcff0c/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:387:15: Generating upb protos for :wrappers_proto failed: (Exit 1): linux-sandbox failed: error executing command 
  (cd /mnt/sfox/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sfox/367cbf405c0894135be861c1e3dcff0c/sandbox/linux-sandbox/2595/execroot/io_bazel && \
  exec env - \
    TMPDIR=/tmp \
  /SCRATCH/sfox/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sfox/install/50a5a3eaeaa5297d31568ab6a3a702d9/linux-sandbox -t 15 -w /mnt/sfox/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sfox/367cbf405c0894135be861c1e3dcff0c/sandbox/linux-sandbox/2595/execroot/io_bazel -w /tmp -w /dev/shm -S /mnt/sfox/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sfox/367cbf405c0894135be861c1e3dcff0c/sandbox/linux-sandbox/2595/stats.out -D -- bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc '--upb_out=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf' '--plugin=protoc-gen-upb=bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/upb/upbc/protoc-gen-upb' '--descriptor_set_in=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/wrappers_proto-descriptor-set.proto.bin' google/protobuf/wrappers.proto)
1690835984.052428132: src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:491: calling fork...
1690835984.052616673: src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:521: child started with PID 2
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-EDC14992/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc)
1690835984.077822719: src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:538: wait returned pid=2, status=0x100
1690835984.077834952: src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:556: child exited normally with code 1
1690835984.109374567: src/main/tools/linux-sandbox.cc:233: child exited normally with code 1
Target //src:bazel-dev failed to build
```